# Unity kinect v2 windows store

Tags: unity-game-engine, windows-store-apps, kinect

I am trying to build a project in Unity3D which uses the Kinect v2 for The Windows store.
To build a windows store app from unity it 1st builds a visual studio project from which you then build the final app.
I am getting errors when I try to build the visual studio project. [The exact same problem as posted here in fact](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/kinect-v2-plugin-windows-store-build-error.292332/) Which has no posted solution.
Here is my error

```
    First-chance exception at 0x76004598 in Template.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Platform::ClassNotRegisteredException ^ at memory location 0x0643F1C0. HRESULT:0x80040154 Class not registered

    WinRT information: Class not registered

    Stack trace:
    combase.dll!76727455()
    vccorlib120_app.dll!5003a438()
    vccorlib120_app.dll!5003b337()
    KinectUnityAddin.dll!50061296()
    KinectUnityAddin.dll!500745af()
    KinectUnityAddin.dll!50062eef()

    If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

I was wondering if the stack overflow community would have any insight into this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've got this working for Unity 5

1. Set up the dll in metro folder to build for WSAPlayer
2. Tick microphone and webcam boxes in player settings, publishing settings, capabilities
3. Build for windows 8.1 (do *not* tick C# project box)
4. One project will be created in the VS solution. Right click on references\ add reference\Windows8.1\Extensions\ then tick the box for WindowsPreview.Kinect (x86 windows 8.1 version)